# Entity framework lambda get null row in joined table

Tags: linq, entity-framework, lambda, entity-framework-6

I have two tables that are connected with a FK.

**Tables**

**Users**

- UserId
- UserName

**LoginStats**

- LoginId
- UserId
- LoginTime

UserId is connected to UserId (of course).

How do I get which users who hasn't logged in using EF 6 and IQueryable. 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have navigation property for LoginStats in User entity:

```
var query = db.Users.Where(u => u.LoginStats == null);
```

If you don't have it, then use group join and select users with empty joined groups:

```
var query = from u in db.Users
            join ls in db.LoginStats
                 on u.UserId equals ls.UserId into g
            where !g.Any()
            select u;
```

Comment: Wow! That was fast! Thank you! I will click solved as soon as the system allow me.